# Apply OrderByDescending after GroupBy

Tags: c#, linq

I have a linq query that is working fine:

```
                    var ListForEmailTableDistinct = ListForEmailTable
                            .GroupBy(o => new
                            {
                                o.ProjectNumber,
                                o.SubProjectNumber,
                                o.SubProjectName,
                                o.ProjectType,
                                o.ProjectManager,
                                o.ErrorType
                            })
                            .Select(o => o.FirstOrDefault());
```

I would like to Order this list by combining (ProjectNumber & SubProjectNumber). Keep all columns, but just order it in a required way.
How I can do that? I have tried already to perform:

```
                    ListForEmailTableDistinct.GroupBy(x => new { x.ProjectNumber, x.SubProjectNumber })
                                    .OrderByDescending(o => o.Key).ToList();
```

but in this case I can't use it further in:

```
                    HTMLTableInString = CreateHTMLTable(ListForEmailTableDistinct,
                            x => (x?.ProjectNumber, "Project number"),
                            x => (x?.SubProjectNumber, "Sub-project number"),
                            x => (x?.SubProjectName, "Sub-project name"),
                            x => (x?.ProjectType, "Sub-project type"),
                            x => (x?.ProjectManager, "Project manager"),
                            x => (x?.ErrorType, "Error type")
                            );
```

Comment: `ListForEmailTable.OrderByDescending(x => x.Some).ThenByDescending(x => x.Another)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use it in your method because by using a `GroupBy` and then a `ToList` you've turned the result into a `List<IGrouping>`.

The correct way to order by multiple fields, as pointed out in the comments by Camilo Terevinto, is to use an `OrderBy` and then a `ThenBy`.

The code would look like this:

```
ListForEmailTableDistinct
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.ProjectNumber)
    .ThenByDescending(x => x.SubProjectNumber);
```